# What happened to System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration class in EF7

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add the MySQL Connector/Net provider for EF7: using one of the following.  But `System.Data.Entity` does not have a class `DbConfiguration` in EF7.  Has this class been moved or am I expected to do something different to add the MySQl provider?

1)Adding the `DbConfigurationTypeAttribute` on the context class:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

or

2)Calling

```
DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySqlEFConfiguration())
```

at the application startup

Answer (score 1):

EF 7 is going to be using different configuration patterns than EF 6. For extensive examples on configuring DbContext, checkout our Wiki page on Github.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Configuring-a-DbContext

*Also*, a MySQL provider for EF 7 is not yet available.